# React JS input type text field default value should be changed

Tags: reactjs

i have created  a button along with text field and kept its defaultValue as "Mahesh" ! Now my requirement is when I click the BUTTON the text field should become empty..that means defaultvalue should change from"mahesh" to empty!

How should i do it ?? please help me any one?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vofMN.jpg)

```
import React,{Component, createRef} from 'react';
export default class App extends Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    this.inputRef=createRef();
    this.state=
    {
    value:"Mahesh"
    }
  }
  handler=(e)=>
  {
     this.setState({value:" "});
    this.inputRef.current.focus();
  }
  render()
  {
    return(
      <div>
       <input ref={this.inputRef} type="text" value={this.state.value}></input>
        <button onClick={this.handler}>edit</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Right now, when you click the button, what happens? Does the text remain the same or does it give an error?

Comment: Its working fine, may be your env errors

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the **edit** button it sets the value to **empty string**.
But when the user wants to input something we have to give **onChange** handler to the textbox. Here's the working code

```
import React,{Component, createRef} from 'react';
export default class App extends Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    this.inputRef=createRef();
    this.state=
    {
    value:"Mahesh"
    }
    }
    
    onClickHandler = (e) =>
    {
    this.setState({value:" "});
    this.inputRef.current.focus();
    }
    
    onChangeHandler = (e) => 
    {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value})    
    }

  render()
  {
    return(
      <div>
       <input ref={this.inputRef} type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange= {this.onChangeHandler} id="box1"></input>
        <button onClick={this.onClickHandler}>edit</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```